# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types when using the minus - sign

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I think this has something to do with using strings and arrays with the number field and minus operator -

This only happens on variable products so i think it relates to child products and i need to use array_sum() to calculate the sum in multi-dimensional arrays

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'non_purchasable_oos_threshold', 10, 2 );
function non_purchasable_oos_threshold( $is_purchasable, $product ) {

    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    $stock_threshold = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_out_of_stock_threshold', true );

    $threshold = $product->get_meta( '_out_of_stock_threshold' );

    if ( $product->managing_stock() && ! empty( $threshold ) ) {

    $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    $new_stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity() - $threshold;

   // var_dump($new_stock_quantity);

    if ( $new_stock_quantity == 0 ) {

    return false;

    }

    return $is_purchasable;

    }
}
```

Why am i getting this error as it says its coming from the minus operator - but i doubt that's the real reason and think it has something to do with my code.

**Update :** I also tried this for variations :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'variations_purchasable_oos_threshold', 10, 2 );
function variations_purchasable_oos_threshold( $is_purchasable, $product ) {

    if ( $product->get_type() == 'variable' ) {

    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $key ) {

    $variation = wc_get_product( $key['variation_id'] );

    $stock = $variation->get_availability();

    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    $stock_threshold = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_out_of_stock_threshold', true );

    $threshold = $product->get_meta( '_out_of_stock_threshold' );

    if ( $product->managing_stock() && ! empty( $threshold ) ) {

    $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    $new_stock_quantity = $stock - $threshold;

   // var_dump($new_stock_quantity);

    if ( $new_stock_quantity == 0 ) {

    return false;

    }

    return $is_purchasable;

    } }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your $threshold read via $product->get_meta is likely a string, so cast it to an int or float.

Comment: I added (int)  get_post_meta( $product_id, '_out_of_stock_threshold', true );

Answer (score 0):

1 added

```
(int) get_post_meta( $product_id, '_out_of_stock_threshold', true );
```

If the string is numeric, resolve to an int if the string is an integer numeric string.

Comment: Can you add some explanation